# How to init var of hostvars to null

Tags: ansible

I would like to reset a varaible to an empty list on all nodes of my inventory, whether it's already existing or not.

The best I come with is:

```
- name: clear union_files list 
  set_fact: 
    hostvars: "{{ hostvars.item | combine({'union_files': []}) }}" 
  loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}" 
  run_once: true
```

But with this code, I've got this error that I don't understand:

```
MSG:

|combine expects dictionaries, got Undefined
```

Why it is saying undefined while I'm setting the dict {'union_files': []}

Have you got any clue? What would by the most ansible way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on with this; first, `hostvars.item` is not the same as `hostvars[item]`; the former syntax is designed for a quick-and-dirty way of dereferencing keys in a `dict`, such as `ansible_version.full` which is not a variable named `full`, it's `ansible_version["full"]`. The latter is looking up a *variable key name* in the `dict`

The second thing going on is that you are attempting to assign `hostvars` as if it were a fact, but it's not a fact, it's a namespace in which facts live. So even if you were to do `hostvars: {{ hostvars[item] }}` it would create a **fact** named `hostvars` in the `hostvars` namespace

If you just want to clear the `union_files` fact, then use `set_fact` as you normally would:

```
- name: clear union_files list 
  set_fact: 
     union_files: []
```

and, assuming the playbook in which that task lives is `hosts: all`, then it will cheerfully set, or reset, `union_files` to `[]` on every host

Comment: Thanks, it's very clear. But why a simple set_fact to a [] is not enough, is because, I'm doing an union of this variable for all hosts later on in my role. And my role is not executed on all host, so I am polluted with the value od union_files from non targetted hosts which list was not clear. I was thinking of a solution: is there a variable that list hosts targetted by a role? I found ansible_play_hosts for the play book, but my role is not executed on all of this ansible_play_hosts, so it does not work.

Comment: In that case, you can guard the `set_fact` for only hosts that already have that variable via `when: union_files is defined and union_files`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matthew,

I finally come up with this solution:

```
- name: clear list 
  set_fact: 
      union_files: [] 
  delegate_to: item 
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}" 
  run_once: true
```

which do the job.